# Ask the compiler to ignore #pragma message

Tags: objective-c, xcode

As said in the title, I want the compiler to ignore pragma message for the time being, so it's easier for me to read and fix actual warnings.  I've done some searching, but there doesn't seem to be any information on it.

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the intrusive pragma messages?

Comment: Does it really matter?  All there is to pragma messages is `#pragma message("123")` and a warning would appear saying `#pragma message Directive` with the next line the string you inputted.  All I want is to have the compiler ignore that warning for now.

Comment: if every #pragma message needs to be suppressed, i'd just search and replace #pragma with //#pragma in the project find and replace. Its not an elegant soln, but should serve the purpose.

Comment: That's why I asked this question if there was a way to do this via the build settings or launch arguments for a more elegant solution, as I may want to undo that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't possible, so the best thing to do would be to mass-edit all the `#pragma`s out:

```
$ cd MySourceFolder
$ find . -name \*.m -exec perl -p -i -n -e 's/^#pragma/\/\/#pragma/' {} \;
```

When you want the `#pragma`'s back again:

```
$ cd MySourceFolder
$ find . -name \*.m -exec perl -p -i -n -e 's/^\/\/#pragma/#pragma/' {} \;
```

If you do this kind of thing alot, I would wrap that in a script, and put it into your `~/bin` directory.